# Java - Creation of loop with static code and object

Tags: java, list, loops

I'm stuck on figuring out this major programming concept...how do I replace repeated code with a loop?

Sample, :

```
System.out.println("Name:");
String name = input.next();

System.out.println("Age");
int age = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Sex");
double sex= input.next();

System.out.println("Location:");
String location= input.next();

System.out.println("Subscribe:");
boolean subscribe= input.nextBoolean();
user.set(name, age, sex, location); // user object would hold this information
user.set(subscribe);
```

I have created a class with mutators and accessors to handle the returns, yet I can't figure out how not to write the above code for five different users without calling user1, user2, user3...etc.

I've played with using a for loop that would count up to five, but I don't know how to direct that towards a user object.

Thoughts? Direction to some references would really help. I'm trying to really understand this concept.

Comment: Create a collection (array or `ArrayList`) of `User` objects. Make a loop. Upon each loop iteration, create a new `User` object, set its values (please create some meaningful setters) and add the object to the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap this code in a function, which will get the data from input, create a new user and return it:

```
 public User getUser() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    User user = new User();

    System.out.println("Name:");
    String name = input.next();

    System.out.println("Age");
    int age = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Sex");
    double sex= input.next();

    System.out.println("Location:");
    String location= input.next();

    System.out.println("Subscribe:");
    boolean subscribe= input.nextBoolean();
    user.set(name, age, sex, location); // user object would hold this information
    user.set(subscribe);

    return user;
}
```

Then you can use it:

- you can use array of objects

  ```
  User[] users = new User[5];
  ```

then you can loop:

```
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        users[i] = getUser();
    }
```

- you can use ArrayList of objects

  ```
  List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      list.add(getUser());
  }
  ```

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing! If I use the array of objects, would I still need to import the package?

Comment: If you're using List and ArrayList, you would need to import those.

Comment: And if you have a regular array, no need to import any specific package.

Comment: @Melquiades - I've tried using your variation of code in both my driver and my main classes, however, I'm getting a cannot find Symbol error for "User". Additionally, my driver class is also showing up with the same error. I'm using the NetBeans IDE and both files are in the same folder. Will they not see each other until I compile? The User function should be visible inside my main class.

Comment: You have user.set(subscribe); <-- what is the type of your user variable? I assumed you have a User class somewhere, so please change it to whatever class you have

Answer (score 0):

First you create an array of users:

```
User[] users = new User[5] ; //Where 5 is the number of objects you want to store.
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){ //Fill it
  users[0] = new User();
}
```

Now you can work with the array:

```
for (User user : users){
  user.set(stuff);
  user.do();
}
```